# Controlling the real-time clock module PCF8563 with python over i2c - understanding smbus

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, real-time-clock

I am trying to control a real-time clock module PCF8563 with python. I connected the module to my Raspberry Pi and I am able to read the clock from the module. I would like to use the internal alarm functionality of the module and control this feature from python.

There are two Python libraries I know, [one here](https://github.com/switchdoclabs/RTC_SDL_PCF8563) and [one here](https://github.com/abelectronicsuk/AlarmPi).

The first one works great but lacks the support for the alarm functionality. The second one cover most of the functions but rely on quick2wire library which I do not know and do not want to use. I actually would like to improve the first one.

I found also a [good documented how-to](http://tronixstuff.com/2013/08/13/tutorial-arduino-and-pcf8563-real-time-clock-ic/) related to this module, but sadly it is for Arduino.

My current problem is, how can I **read and set specific bits** from the bytes I get from the registries over the i2c bus. With:

```
import smbus

bus = smbus.SMBus(0)
returndata = bus.read_byte_data(0x51, 0x01)
```

I get one byte from registry 0x01. I need to translate the return vale from bcd to decimal, but how can I get the third bit of this byte ? And how can I change it.

Taken from the Arudino how-to:

> ... check bit 3 of the register at 0x01 (the “AF” alarm flag bit). If it’s 1 – it’s alarm time! Then you can turn the alarm off by setting that bit to zero. Using hardware, first set bit 1 of register 0x01 to 1 – then whenever an alarm occurs, current can flow into pin 3 of the PCF8563.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer was: learning how to use the **bit-masks** and how **bit-shifting** works. The [German Wikipedia site](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitfeld) was quite helpful.  After checking the data-sheet for the PCF8563 I was able to implement some of the missing functionality. For further progress [see my GitHub repository](https://github.com/karlitos/RTC_SDL_PCF8563).

I found probably an error in the [Arduino related How-To](http://tronixstuff.com/2013/08/13/tutorial-arduino-and-pcf8563-real-time-clock-ic/#comment-179363), I noticed the author, see the comments under the linked article.